# Is locally embedded ML kit library making any network call to google server?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I would like to embed ML kit library to my android application. I read the terms and condition and noted a confusing statement.

The statement from the link(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms) is below

> Network request sender IP addresses. Used for remote configuration diagnostics. Collected IP addresses are retained temporarily.

I am planning to use embedded version not the play service one. Is the library making any call to any server to send my ip address or How it is working?

Answer (score 2):

Hi Deepu George Jacob,

ML Kit updated the Term and Privacy page recently. Please refer to that page for most up-to-date information. https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/terms

Here is also a specific page for "[Prepare for Google Play’s data disclosure requirements](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/android-data-disclosure)".